# VBA Count - how does it works

Tags: excel, vba

Below is a part of code (self-learning):

```
Sub CopyWorkbook()
    Dim aw As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set aw = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set y = Application.Workbooks.Open("S:\Proefbalanse\PastelTB\Segmented General Ledger Trial Balance.XLS")
    'To rename worksheet in Pastel File
    y.Sheets(1).Name = "SGLT"

    For i = 3 To aw.Sheets.Count
        Set sh = SGLT
```

Please explain "For i = 3 To aw.Sheets.Count"

Does it means the 3rd sheet from the left in a workbook of 20 Sheets, or does it means "Sheet 3". If I want to set Sheet 13 to SGLT, what must the code be: "For i = ? To aw.Sheets.Count"

Thank you for explaining.

Kind regards

Johan

Comment: `y.Sheets(1).Name = "SGLT"` renames the first sheet in the workbook to "SGLT"  The loop set i to three and then runs the loop until i larger than the number of total sheets but unless we know what i is used for we can't say any more than that.  Do you have the rest of the code?

Comment: As it doesn't mention *Sheet 3* by name, it means the third sheet from the left. If you want it to start at a specific sheet, you need to tell it to start at that sheet by index.

Comment: For i = 3 To aw.Sheets.Count
        Set sh = SGLT
        On Error Resume Next
        Set sh = y.Worksheets(aw.Worksheets(i).Name)
        On Error GoTo 0
          If TypeName(sh) <> "SGLT" Then
           sh.Range("A:F").Copy aw.Worksheets(i).Range("A1")
           
       End If
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    y.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aw is your active excel workbook. It may have multiple sheets. Let’s say it has 20 sheets.

aw.Sheets.Count will be 20.

The For i = 3 to 20 means that all statements in the For loop will work on sheet #3 (3rd from the left), then sheet #4 and so on till sheet #20

To make the code work only on sheet 3, just do this:

```
For i = 3 to 3
   ...rest of your code
End for
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response, what must I change so that the code only work in Sheet #3 and not in the rest?

Comment: @Johan I have updated the answer so that it works only on Sheet 3. Give it a try.

Comment: @Johan Awesome. To put closure to your question, could you mark this as answered? You can do that by clicking on a check mark by my answer.